# RST, ACK after sending huge portion of data

Tags: tcp, imap, reset, wireshark, mtu

I have an IMAP server (Dovecot), on which I am trying to create 1,200 mailboxes (for performance testing). The server successfully creates the mailboxes.

After this operation I then want to list all created folders. The server sends some data, however, after some time (nearly 1 second) the CLIENT sends `RST`, `ACK` to the server in response to the server responding with IMAP protocol's command about the list of created folders.

Here is my Wireshark dump snippet:

> ```
> IMAP: Src Port: imap (143), Dst Port: 56794 (56794), Seq: 29186, Ack: 20533, Len: 24
> IMAP: Src Port: 56794 (56794), Dst Port: imap (143), Seq: 20533, Ack: 29210, Len: 15
> IMAP: Src Port: imap (143), Dst Port: 56794 (56794), Seq: 29210, Ack: 20548, Len: 16384
> TCP: 56794 > imap [ACK] Seq=20548 Ack=45594 Win=49408 Len=0 TSV=3940902 TSER=3940902
> IMAP: Src Port: imap (143), Dst Port: 56794 (56794), Seq: 45594, Ack: 20548, Len: 16384
> TCP: 56794 > imap [RST, ACK] Seq=20548 Ack=61978 Win=49408 Len=0 TSV=3940902 TSER=3940902
> ```

**Edit:** Well, I think I figured out why **RST** flag is sent by client. The reason is server exceed **MTU** value for my **loopback** interface. I have checked similar behavior for sample Mina server - and all is OK there, i.e. huge packets are spited by TCP/IP protocol. So **Dovecot** can't manage packets wisely. But I have my own IMAP server (based on MINA) and the problem still persist there!

**So why TCP/IP protocol manages sent packets (split them according to MTU value) wisely only for some apps but not for all?**

Comment: Can you share more details from Wireshark for the last lines? It's hard to work out why the RST was generated with the information so far.

Comment: Pls, see my Edit. I have shared only valuable info from Wireshark - what info do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption about the causation of a TCP Reset being sent is incorrect. If you've exceeded the MTU, that's not managed by TCP. It's managed at the IP layer and an ICMP "fragmentation required" message will be sent to the client. Such a message **should** then cause the client to fragment the packets at the IP layer. This is not happening in your case based on the information that you've shared.

Regarding the loopback interface, this traffic doesn't go anywhere near the loopback interface, is it not two separate devices?

Sadly, your trace file still doesn't offer any insight into why this packet -

```
IMAP: Src Port: imap (143), Dst Port: 56794 (56794), Seq: 45594, Ack: 20548, Len: 16384
```

causes a TCP reset. There's nothing really further that I can deduce from this information.

TCP has an option called [Maximum Segment size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_segment_size), which is similar but also different :) The TCP/IP stack is independent of applications and does not apply different settings to each application, it's system-wide.

Edit: Looking at you packet capture, there's nothing indicative of a MTU issue. There's no ICMP traffic anywhere so I suspect that it's not an issue. If there's a MTU issue, it should have happened in the previous response because both LIST responses from the IMAP server are of identical size and there's no issue with the window sizes.

The only thing that I can see is in relation to the first element of the final response (before the RST) where part of the reply looks to be malformed (see the attachment). There's something going wrong in the IMAP application and the data it's replying with is malformed.[image: imap response] - see the difference with the bottom two responses that are consistent with all other LIST responses in the pcap.

Comment: 1) Again, what do you want to see in my Wireshark dump? I have provided already the end of conversation. Please see all dump http://www.4shared.com/file/yE60EDK9/rst.html. 2) I don't pretend on academic terms - is TCP or IP are responsible for watching MTU but I think the problem is near MTU. When I change MTU - RST flag is sent after exceeding this value. 3) Yes I have client and server on localhost that's why I'am talking here about lo interface.

Comment: 1) I wanted the full dump to see what was going on at an application level. 2) MTU - fragmentation is in the IP header, nothing to do with this issue. 3) Thanks, that wasn't clear. Another reason why fragmentation is irrelevant. - Thanks for the full dump!!

Comment: Data sent from IMAP server are malformed because client sends RST while server response :) If you sure that MTU is not the problem here - how can you explain that after changing MTU value the server sends last packet with length almost equal to the new MTU value and after this client sends RST nevertheless?

Comment: The malformed data is sent before the RST, look at the dump again. I don't have the dump showing the the MTU change. If you are only using localhost, I don't see how a MTU change affects it. Does the increase in MTU affect your MSS, have you looked?

Comment: OK, here is a dump showing the MTU change: http://www.4shared.com/file/ymJ90Y1s/rst_mtu_555.html . I've set it to 555. You can see that response is interrupted earlier than in my previous dump. How will you explain this?